# Bind to an element in the DataTemplate in DataGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have xaml something like below. I am not able to bind the chkExtract checkbox to ChkHeaderExtract. I want to do something for ChkHeaderExtract like IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=chkExtract" and so on}. But I am unable to access the chkExtract name. Also I am unable to access the chkExtract control from anywhere in the cs file. Could anyone help me how do I do the binding.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DgEntities" FrozenColumnCount="13" IsReadOnly="True" MaxWidth="854" Height="444" CanUserAddRows="false" SelectedItem="{Binding GetSelectedRow,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" ItemsSource="{Binding JobEntitiesCollectionViewSource.View, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Entity" Width="202" MaxWidth="202" MinWidth="202"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="138" MaxWidth="138" MinWidth="138">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Margin="5" Content="{Binding ExtractStatus, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Command="{Binding DataContext.HyperlinkCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=DgEntities}" Cursor="Hand" MouseDoubleClick="Control_OnMouseDoubleClick" >
                                    <Button.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TxtblkStyleExtract}" TextDecorations="None"><InlineUIContainer>
                                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                                </InlineUIContainer></TextBlock>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Button.Template>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="40" MaxWidth="40" MinWidth="40">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>

                            <CheckBox x:Name="ChkHeaderExtract" Width="26" Command="{Binding DataContext.HeaderExtractCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.ExtractHeaderCheck,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Mode=TwoWay}" />

                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>

                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                            <DataTemplate>

                                <CheckBox  x:Name="chkExtract" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding DataContext.IndividualExtractCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" IsChecked="{Binding ExtractIsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

                            </DataTemplate>

                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
 </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that `chkExtract` is inside of a DataTemplate, which means it has no knowledge of names outside of it.

This also means that the items named within the DataTemplate can't be seen in the .cs file (code-behind)

The best way to get the checkboxes affecting one another would be via the ViewModel;  Bind `chkExtract.IsChecked` to properties of the objects in the collection that the grid uses, and then to bind the header's `ChkHeaderExtract.IsChecked` to a property on the DataGrid's ViewModel.  That way, you can control their interaction using C# code in the ViewModel.

Comment: I did that through the view model and it all works well. But in the future if I come across a similar situation what would be the best way of doing changing xaml or modify view model? Thanks.

Comment: When it's a really simple binding (i.e. a Textbox's visibility being bound to a Label's visibility), I prefer binding the items directly in xaml, but whenever it gets at all convoluted, I find the ViewModel better, since it gives you better control.  As for checkboxes and the like, I'd usually bind `IsChecked` to a property on the ViewModel, since this is often information that you want to have available for business logic.